# createjs : color certain parts of bitmap

Tags: canvas, bitmap, createjs, easeljs

I'm currently struggling to find a solution for the following problem:

I load a bitmap (png) into the canvas, which consists of several parts. I'd like to color those parts separately.

After some research I found out, that the following approach could do the job:

1. Load the parts separately into the canvas and fill the affected areas within the parts with a certain color.
2. Use the Threshold Filter in order to search for a particular color within the bmp and change it to the desired one.
3. Update cache or stage.

If this might work, how do I use the Threshold Filter? I just found an example in the github repo but can't figure out how to work with it since the documentation doesn't contain that filter.

Or is there even a better way to solve my problem?

I'd really appreciate any help or suggestions!

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**

I might have understood how that filter works, but please correct me, if I'm wrong:

`target.filters = [new createjs.ThresholdFilter(<R>, <G>, <B>, <trueValue>, <falseValue>)];`

RGB -> The RGB Threshold Value
If the channel values of the current pixel are under the Threshold -> set color to the falseValue e.g. 0xdf1318.

If falseValue is set to `true`, any pixel that does not fit, won't be changed and keeps its color.

Comment: Please include any relevant code - what have you got so far? what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: The ThresholdFilter has a working sample in the same folder as the JavaScript file.

Comment: @etov I haven't any code yet, since every approach wasn't feasible (e.g. create an inverted picture of the original and use this as mask, but the documentation says only shapes can be used as such). That's why I wanted to clearify which possibilites exist.

Comment: @Lanny I meant that example but unfortunately I receive an error: 

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`


There is this command:



`bmp.filters = [new createjs.ThresholdFilter(value, value, value, 0xFF0000, true)];`

Could you explain the input parameters? The first three would describe the RGB values I guess?

Thank you both!

Comment: Filters use pixel data, so looks like your loading cross-origin images, which won't work (hence the error). For the params, have a look at the demo, as well as the source. While it isn't officially documented, it has all the documentation in the class. https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/extras/Filters/ThresholdFilter.js#L42

Comment: @Lanny Thanks mate! Works fine now, awesome.